# Get selected fields from Java POJO during serialisation and deserialisation

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, jackson

Suppose I am having POJO which contains 10 fields and getter/setter for each one. I would like to get the selected fields from that POJO during serialization and deserialization depending on some conditions.
Can i achieve this using Jackson?? If so then can some on help me out and give some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serialization, you could read "[Filtering properties with Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)" for some possibilities.

As to deserialization, one possibility would be to first bind to a Map or JsonNode, then pick properties from there -- filtering options do not work deserialization.

Comment: yeah thanks StaxMan....Json view can also be used but jackson filtering gives dynamic filtering..